# how to split an array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc-4, jqplot

I am working on jqplot chart.
untill data of chart is splitting by comma I don't get any problem in rendering chart.

Before putting dynamic data into chart I have script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var data = [
    ['Test1', 230], ['Test2', 330], ['Test3', 430], ['Test4', 530], ['Test5', 630]
  ];

            var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot('chart1', [data],
    {
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                showDataLabels: true
            }
        },
        legend: { show: true, location: 'e' }
    }
  );
        });
    </script>
```

and it looks like-

[image]

**After putting dynamic data-**

```
@model List<Myapplication.models.mytable>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var data = [
    ['@Model[i].AccountHead', '@Model[i].AccID']
  ];

            var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot('chart1', [data],
    {
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                showDataLabels: true
            }
        },
        legend: { show: true, location: 'e' }
    }
  );
        });
    </script>
}
```

Now it plots the chart but overlaps each entry and it looks weird-

[image]

The one way is to split that data array by 'comma', So i tried -

```
var data = [
        ['@Model[i].AccountHead', '@Model[i].AccID']
      ];

        var splitdata= data.split(',');
 var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot('chart1', splitdata,
    {
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                showDataLabels: true
            }
        },
        legend: { show: true, location: 'e' }
    }
  );
        });
```

But splitting on array is not working for me.

How can I split an array in jQuery or any other way of doing it?

My application is built in ASP.NET MVC4 Razor.

Comment: you only passed one entry into the chart... your second attempt shouldn't work because arrays don't have a split method.

Comment: I think it's becoz data contains only Holder values...

Comment: You are looping around the data so it always overwrite the values..That's why it showing  pie chart only filled by Holder value .

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function ()
         {
            pieData();
        });   
          function pieData()
    {
      var data =[];
  for(int i = 0; i <@Model.Count; i++)
   {
  data.push(['@Model[i].AccountHead', '@Model[i].AccID']);  
    }
        var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot('chart1', [data],
      {
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            showDataLabels: true
        }
    },
    legend: { show: true, location: 'e' }
     });
  }
   </script>
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: You seem to be doing it fine, I don't get rid of overlapping still. Even if i replaced dynamic data with `['header',3232]` But still I get second Image.

Comment: if you pass only 'header' then it shows the same result .Try replacing data with [['header',10] ,['header1',20]]

Answer (score 0):

the array is wrong defined.

try this attempt:

```
var splitdata= [];
splitdata[ 0 ] = '@Model[i].AccountHead';
splitdata[ 1 ] = '@Model[i].AccID';
```

or..

```
var splitdata= new Array( '@Model[i].AccountHead', '@Model[i].AccID'); 
var splitdata= [ '@Model[i].AccountHead', '@Model[i].AccID' ];
```

hope it helps..